# I can't understand the logical operator error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, logical-operators

I was coding in node, so I got an error, will you explain this error to me?

When I write a statement `console.log(Email||Password||Song)`

It's returning the value of **Email** variable.

---

But when I write statement `console.log(!Email||!Password||!Song);` 
It's returning actual value which is **true/false**

Can you Please explain me

Comment: I found this video very helpful in understanding logical operators, may help you as well:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHpLGco_jSk&list=PLaZSdijfCCJDm33pC1WX56jTW1r9Ln1EG&index=20

Answer (score 0):

So, first up the `or (||)` operator:

```
a || b === a if a is truthy, otherwise b
```

So the `or` operator isn't strictly useful for boolean types. For example, you could set a default value for data like

```
function makePerson(name, age) {
  return { name: name, age: age || 0 }
}
```

Next, the `not (!)` operator:

```
!a === false if a is truthy, true otherwise
```

So note that the `!` operator strictly provides boolean outputs.

So with your example,

```
Email||Password||Song
```

will be `Email` if truthy, then `Password` if truthy, and finally `Song`

```
!Email||!Password||!Song
```

is going to end up evaluating to something like

```
false||false||true
```

or

```
true||false||false
```

etc. By adding in the unary not, you're effectively casting all your inputs to booleans, and the output of the or operator is the type of its inputs.